# How would I go about separating numbers in a string and making them their own values?

Tags: javascript, html, percentage

I'm making a program where the user enters a fraction, then some JavaScript code will figure out the percentage of the given fraction.

For example, figure I enter 2/4, the program would return 50%.

I'm wondering if there's a function in JavaScript that will separate the numerator and denominator from the given value and make them into their own separate values. Here's my code so far:

HTML:

```
    <!doctype html> 
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Percentage finder JavaScript</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/Index.css" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1 id="Head">Enter your fraction:</h1>
      <form>
         <input id="fraction" autofocus="on" placeholder="i.e: 1/4"></input>
         <input type="submit" id="sbmt"></input> 
      </form>
   </body>
   <script src="Scripts/js/Index.js" type="text/javaScript"></script>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('sbmt').onclick = function() {

var x = document.getElementById('fraction').value;

}
```

Comment: "make them into their own separate values" - what do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean making them into their own variables, sorry that wasn't worded well.

Comment: can you give an example? (in wording :))

Comment: show how the result should be outputted. Should it replace the initial input or just be on `console.log`?

Comment: say that the value I enter into "fraction" is 2/4 I want to be able to to have a variable for the 2 and one for the 4.

Comment: what if I can give a percentage without variables right away?

Comment: What should happen if the user enters `2/4/8` either deliberately or by accident?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the user gives input as `value_1 / value_2`, without parentheses, multiplication signs etc...:

```
document.getElementById('sbmt').onclick = function() {
    var value = document.getElementById('fraction').value;
    var array = value.split(/\//);
    var a = +array[0];
    var b = +array[1];
    var result = 100 * (a / b) + '%'; // or just 100 * a / b
}
```

ES6:

```
document.getElementById('sbmt').onclick = function() {
    const value = document.getElementById('fraction').value;
    const [a, b] = value.split(/\//).map(x => +x);
    const result = 100 * (a / b) + '%'; // or just 100 * a / b
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get numerator and denominator from the fraction using split() method.
For example:

```
var x = document.getElementById('fraction').value;
var y = x.split('/');
var percentage = y[0]/y[1]*100;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the same as the other answers but I figured I might as well contribute:

```
var parts = x.split('/');
var percentage = parts[0]*100/parts[1]
```

Comment: @Suever because I had already written it by the time I saw that they had answered, because I'm new to StackExchange and had difficulties with the "Code Sample" button that set me back.

Comment: Sorry didn't realize this was literally just posted. This showed up in the review queue which is why I commented. Carry on!

Comment: @Suever No problem, and I'm just shocked that you actually accepted my comment and didn't tear me a new one .-. People on here sure are nicer and more rational than other places of the internet.